# dplyr recode for qoute elements

Tags: r

Suppose I wanted to recode a vector such like:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
v<-sample(c("Y", "N", ""), 20, TRUE)
recode(v, `Y`=1, `N`=0, `""`=NA)
Error: `""` has type 'logical' not 'double'
```

My question is how to recode the element `""` in `v`.

Comment: Try recode(v, `Y` = 1, `N` = 0, .default = NA_real_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
recode(v, `Y`=1, `N`=0, `""` = NA_real_)
```

Or use `NA_integer`

```
recode(v, `Y`=1L, `N`=0L, `""` = NA_integer_)
```

---

Or another option is `case_when`

```
tibble(v) %>%
      mutate(v = case_when(v=='Y' ~1, v=='N' ~0, TRUE~NA_real_)) %>%
      .$v
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
NA^(!nzchar(v))*(v=='Y')
```